# PHP and jQuery insert into MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to insert data into mySQL using jQuery. The code does not return any error and no any result as well. Please help me to sort this out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var data;
    var eid = 101;
    data = "eid=" + eid;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      data += "&Text_" + (i + 1) + "=" + $("#Text_" + (i + 1)).val();
      data += "&Amount_" + (i + 1) + "=" + $("#Amount_" + (i + 1)).val();
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      cache: false,
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        if (!response.error) {
          $("#msg").addClass('alert-success').html(response.msg);
        } else {
          $("#msg").addClass('alert-danger').html(response.msg);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="Allowance1 " name="Text[]" id="Text_1" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="1001.00" name="Amount[]" id="Amount_1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="Allowance 2" name="Text[]" id="Text_2" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="1002.00" name="Amount[]" id="Amount_2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="Allowance 3" name="Text[]" id="Text_3" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="1003.00" name="Amount[]" id="Amount_3" /></td>
</tr>
```

I am adding the process.php snippet also in order to know where is the error.

> process.php

```
$eid=$_POST['eid'];
$length = sizeof($_POST["Text"]);   
$i=1;
while ($i<=$length){
    if(!empty($_POST['Text'][$i])) {
        $Text = $_POST['Text'][$i];
        $Amount =  $_POST['Amount'][$i]; 

        $msg = array('status' => !$error, 'msg' => 'Failed! updation-1');           
        if(!$error) {
            $sql = "UPDATE TblCustom SET Text='" . $Text . "', Amount='" . $Amount ."' WHERE ID='$eid'";                
            $status = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
            $msg = array('error' => $error, 'msg' => 'Success! updation : '. $sql );
        }
        else {
            $msg = array('error' => $error, 'msg' => 'Failed! updation-2 ');
        }

    }
    echo json_encode($msg);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the code that you are using in process.php

Comment: You are specifying `dataType: "json"`, but the actual format that you are using is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (name=value, separated with &).
That alone might be the cause of your php script's failure. Remove `dataType` property and check if that helps.

Comment: @RohitAilani  process.php snippet added

Comment: @KamilLatosinski commented the //datatype line but still same

Comment: Make `var_dump($_POST)` and inspect the data format. You are creating data like: `['Text_1' => 'value']`, but your php script expects `['Text' => ['value', 'value']]`. Btw., you have a huge SQL Injection hole. Google it out and replace `mysql_` function with PDO and  `bindValue`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 problems.

Problem number one and two are related. Firstly, you are specifying `dataType: 'json'`, but you are passing your data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. Secondly, your php script expects data to be in the following format:

```
$_POST = [
    'Text' => ['text_1', 'text_2', 'text_3'],
    'Amount' => ['amount_1', 'amount_2', 'amount_3']
];
```

While your data looks something like this:

```
$_POST = [
    'Text_1' => 'text_1',
    'Text_2' => 'text_2'
    // and so on
];
```

The single fix to this problem is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {

    const data = {
      // we are grabbing all inputs with name=Text[] 
      // and mapping them to array containing their values.
      // The `...` is a spread operator introduced 
      // with the new js standard (ES6), 
      // that converts jQuery object to regular javascript
      // array of inputs.
      // you can do all of this with a for loop, but the map way
      // is prefered
      Text: [...$('input[name="Text[]"]')].map(input => input.value),
      Amount: [...$('input[name="Amount[]"]')].map(input => input.value)
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      cache: false,
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        if (!response.error) {
          $("#msg").addClass('alert-success').html(response.msg);
        } else {
          $("#msg").addClass('alert-danger').html(response.msg);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The third problem is that have created an SQL Injection vulnerability. That means some bad guy can inject and SQL statement into `Text` variable, which then you are putting directly into your sql update, thus he can do whatever he wants (for example drop all database).

[More on SQL Injection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jKylhJtPmI)

The solution is simple: use PDO and `bindValue` method.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // 500 means internal server error
    // that's handy information for the client-side
    http_send_status(500);
    echo json_encode([
        'error' => [
            'message' => 'Unable to connect to database'
        ]
    ]);
    exit;
}

$eid = $_POST['eid'];
$Text = $_POST['Text'][$i];
$Amount = $_POST['Amount'][$i];

$sql = "UPDATE TblCustom SET Text = :text, Amount = :amount WHERE ID = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(':text', $Text);
$stmt->bindValue(':amount', $Amount);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $eid);

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    // 400 means something went wrong when updating
    // also a handy information for the client-side
    http_send_status(400);
    echo json_encode([
        'error' => [
            'message' => 'Unable to update'
        ]
    ]);
    exit;
}

// 204 measn everything went okay, and we don't return anything
http_send_status(204);
exit;
```

Hint: if you are sending correct status codes the jQuery lets you handle errors like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(response) {
        // this code will be executed
        // only when status code == 2xx
    },
    error: function(response) {
        // this code will be executed
        // only when status code == 4xx | 5xx (if I remember correctly)
    },
    always: function(response) {
        // this code will be executed no matter what
        // as the name implies
    },
});
```

So there is no need for additional if statements.

Comment: Thanks for the SQL Injection Part. The given code was a good example how not to do Communication between Website and Database

Comment: @Kamil Latosinski thanks for the code and information of sql injection, This is still under testing phase will take care of security measure as per your advise.  I dont find any reference to '$i' . **$Text = $_POST['Text'][$i];**

Comment: Well, there isn't one. The PHP code sample just demonstrates how to use PDO in your case. You have to adjust the code to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form_signup" name="form_signup">
   <tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="Allowance1 " name="Text[]" id="Text_1" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="1001.00" name="SAmount[]" id="Amount_1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="Allowance 2" name="Text[]" id="Text_2" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="1002.00" name="SAmount[]" id="Amount_2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" value="Allowance 3" name="Text[]" id="Text_3" /></td>
  <td><input type="text" value="1003.00" name="SAmount[]" id="Amount_3" /></td>
</tr>
 <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up!"/>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form_signup").click(function() {
       $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      cache: false,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
          alert(response);
        if (!response.error) {
          $("#msg").addClass('alert-success').html(response.msg);
        } else {
          $("#msg").addClass('alert-danger').html(response.msg);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>

process.php
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
 ?>
```

Comment: Any explanations of what you did or what the problem was? A code block alone isn't so helpful.

Comment: @Nikit Barochiya data: $(this).serialize(), does not help

Comment: work is properly And serialize() get  form all data.  check js file work is properly